# What requirement if any should a Java Code meet to get a Signed Certificate from a trusted source like DigiCert or Symantec?

Tags: java, ssl, code-signing

I was just wondering if the SSL companies like Digicert give trusted certificates to any organization/software that pays the fee or is there a verification process they do that the code is actually not malicious?

-Thanks
AB

Comment: They only verify the signer (company) when issuing the certificate. Once issued they can not possibly check what you sign with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code signing is meant only to provide assurance as to the author/source of the code. In no way does it guarentee that the code is not malicious.

The theory is that if you trust the source, you should trust their code